# Version problems with symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle in my existing project

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-cmf

I started yesterday and I tried to install the symfony/cmf bundles in my existing project. Unfortunately I am not so familiar with composer and it ended with huge mess. Now I reverted my project and try it again with clean head, but the same issue today.

I followed the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/creating_a_cms/getting-started.html#initializing-the-project) and the PHPCR tables are successfully initialized. But the next step causes problems with package versions (symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle).

Here my requirements and the composer message:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",

    "symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle": "1.0.*@alpha",
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle": "1.1.*",

    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",

    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.1.*",
    "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "symfony-cmf/routing": "1.2.*"
},
```

and the messages

```
Problem 1
- The requested package symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
- symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
Problem 3
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha9 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha8 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha7 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha6 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle ~1.1.0-RC1 -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha5 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle ~1.1.0-RC1 -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle ~1.1.0-RC1 -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha3 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha2 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha10 requires symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
- symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.0-alpha1 requires aferrandini/urlizer dev-master -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle 1.0.*@alpha -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle[1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0-alpha10, 1.0.0-alpha2, 1.0.0-alpha3, 1.0.0-alpha4, 1.0.0-alpha5, 1.0.0-alpha6, 1.0.0-alpha7, 1.0.0-alpha8, 1.0.0-alpha9].
```

I also tried the links below this messages, but it does not helped me. What I did yesterday was I tried to adjust the required versions, but the problems just moved from one package to another.

It would be really nice, if someone could please help me with a concrete solution or a good tip how I can solve it by myself (no, thats no google. thats the way I tried yesterday for many hours without a solution ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry you are facing this issue. The fact is that we are in a somewhat messy situation, which is especially bad since one of our lengthy tutorials mentions this Bundle. RoutingAutoBundle is indeed currently not easily instable. We want to soon release CMF 1.2 which will finally feature a stable release of RoutingAutoBundle. There are several open PRs on this Bundle. If you are motivated to help out have a look there and comment on the tickets to get in contact with the authors.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for your answer. I think the CMF-Bundle might a good one with a lot great functions, but I just need a simple and fast solution to get content in my project. Now I spend already the third day with that bundle and I can not see it running. Even one part works, another part breaks. Is this part necessary or is there a workaroud to get the cmf running?

Comment: the easiest way to get started from my point of view is to use the sandbox or the standard edition.

Comment: That does not work for me, because there were also some installation problems with these versions, too. The second point is I need it in my existing project. I just need a small and simple content management and now I developed an own solution for me.